# xslt condition to check if each row of a table has same or different data

Tags: xslt

Is there any condition in xslt that will help me to find if a table field, say Name, has different value? I have a set of different names with me in a xml file. I need to display each name in a different color on the html table. If there are 2 rows that has same Name field, then they should both be of uniform color. Is there any if condition that will help me to achieve this requirement in xslt?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can `count()` the number of nodes with the given name.

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="Name/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="count" select="count(//row[Name/text() = $value])"/>
<xsl:if test="$count &gt; 0"> <!-- do something --> </xsl:if>
```

Or you can check if there is a preceding or following node with a Name:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" select="Name/text()"/>
<xsl:variable name="node" select="preceding::.//row[Name/text() = $value]|following::.//row[Name/text() = $value]"/>
<xsl:if test="count($node) &gt; 0"> <!-- do something --> </xsl:if>
```